# C flex code debugging

Tags: c, flex-lexer

In the following code which is a lexical recognizer in C language:

```
    %{
#include <stdio.h>
void showToken(char*);
%}

%option yylineno
%option noyywrap
digit ([0-9])
letter ([a-zA-Z])
%%

letter(letter | digit)*             showToken("id");
(digit)(digit)*(.(digit)(digit)*)?      showToken("num");
[(),:;.]                printf("%c",yytext[0]); 
[ \n]
(==|<>|<|<=|>|>=)       showToken("relop");
(+|-)                   showToken("addop");
(*|/)                   showToken("mulop");
(=)                 showToken("assign");
(&&)                    showToken("and");
(||)                    showToken("or");
(!)                 showToken("not");
.                   {   
                    printf("Lexical Error");
                    exit(0);
                    }

%%
void showToken(char* name){
    printf("<%s,%s>",name,yytext);
}
%%
```

I get the following errors, why is that happening I think I wrote the code correctly!
I have done too many changes in the code but it doesn't compile.

```
~/hedor>lex -t lexical.l > lexical.c
lexical.l:13: unrecognized rule
lexical.l:17: unrecognized rule
lexical.l:17: unrecognized rule
lexical.l:17: unrecognized rule
lexical.l:17: unrecognized rule
lexical.l:17: unrecognized rule
lexical.l:18: unrecognized rule
lexical.l:18: unrecognized rule
lexical.l:18: unrecognized rule
lexical.l:18: unrecognized rule
lexical.l:18: unrecognized rule
lexical.l:21: unrecognized rule
lexical.l:21: unrecognized rule
lexical.l:21: unrecognized rule
lexical.l:21: unrecognized rule
```

Comment: it looks like its failing to understand the digit, letter etc. try replacing them with the relevant regex - this may or may not help, but here is flex input generated by bnfc that is known to work: http://code.google.com/p/fridgescript/source/browse/trunk/src/bnfc%20output/FridgeScript.l

Comment: Use source control next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues in your regular expressions:

Line 13, actually the error is in the 12, do not add blanks in the RE, it breaks the expression and does not work as expected:

```
letter(letter|digit)*             showToken("id");
```

Line 17, the `+` is a special character, so escape it with `\`:

```
(\+|-)                   showToken("addop");
```

Line 18, the same with characters `*` and `/`:

```
(\*|\/)                   showToken("mulop");
```

Line 21, the same with `|`:

```
(\|\|)                    showToken("or");
```

That should fix the compilation errors, but note the comment by @JameySharp below, you likely want to write the `digit` and `letter` references using curly braces: `{digit}` and `{letter}`.

Comment: You beat me to it. :-) In addition to those syntax errors, I believe the references to "digit" and "letter" need to be in curly braces.

Comment: @JameySharp: You are right. Without the braces the syntax is correct, but it matches the literal word `letter` in the input, and that's probably not what the OP wants...

Comment: thanks for your help ,but 2 things I did not understand what is a special character? and why this is not correct (digit),(letter).

Comment: @user1812694: Special chars are chars that have special meaning, instead of representing themselves. For example, `a` matches only a letter `a`, not special, but `|` is used to create an alternative, not to match a literal `|`, so it is special. There are quite a few special chars (you yourself used some of them): `*`, `?`, `(`, `)`, `|`, ` ` and others. About using `(digit)` the `()` are special and they are skipped, but the `d`, `i`, `g` and `t` are not special, so they match themselves. That RE would match only a literal `digit`, not the RE defined previously, for that you use `{digit}`.

Comment: did you mean that if I write /n it would be understood as new line instead of "\n" ?

Comment: @user1812694: Of course not! `a/b` is used to match `a` only if followed by `b`, so `/n` is nonsense. Nothing to do with `\n`. If you want a new-line write `\n`, if you want a back-slash and an en write `\\n`, if you want a slash and an en write `\/n`, if you want just an en write `n`.

Comment: do you have any good resources to learn about flex because I am new to it!

Comment: @user1812694: I find the official [`info flex`](http://flex.sourceforge.net/manual/) contents to be usually good enough for starters.

Comment: @flashdisk: I suggest you read Thomas Niemann's "A Compact Guide to Lex & Yacc" (http://www.epaperpress.com/lexandyacc/)